# Add ons not installing/showing up in Blender 2.91.2

Tags: add-on, installation

I'm using Blender 2.91.2 and I've been trying to install [this add on](https://www.blendermarket.com/products/audvis?ref=2) that I bought. I tried to install it in User Preferences, but nothing ever shows up/reacts when I do. I've tried installing just the .py file and copying the unzipped folder into scripts/addons, but still nothing shows up. I've also tried enabling Developer Extras. I've tried this with several other add ons and none work.

I'm trying to make an animation move to sound, and there doesn't seem to be a default add on that does that. If I can't get this add on to work, are there other methods of making sound sync to animation?